# Send answers of deleted question via email after moderator action

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have asked a [question (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653916/cakephp-acl-by-prefix) and received some answers, but after few days it was deleted after moderation.

How can I get the answers back, as some of them have solved my problem.  Is it possible to send them to my email?

I don't remember the user who answer my question, so I can't make direct contact to get the answers again.

Comment: If your question was deleted, then it was not suitable for these sites. Nice for you that somehow you got answers anyway, but I think it's a bit too much to ask for even more than that?

Answer (score 3):

Your question was answered by [Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558605/tyler), but that won't get you very far, as there's no way to privately contact users unless they have chosen to provide contact details in their profile.

For your records, here is the answer, copied directly from the deleted question:

[image]

As for why the question was deleted, it was deleted by a moderator presumably because it was deemed to be of "low quality" and not useful to the rest of the community. **In the future, please learn from this experience and try to put more time into writing better quality questions.** Not only will they be more likely to stick around, but you'll also be more likely to get good answers.

The answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this) contain some hints and tips on how to write better questions.